# How to investigate " Attempt to free unreferenced scalar"

Tags: perl, debugging

A Perl script (which uses a load of locally-written modules, and is under active development) has just started producing sporadic

" Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0xa6e685c, Perl interpreter: 
0x96d9008 during global destruction."

messages. This are always repeatable, in the sense that a particular sequence of commands always produces the message if it ever does, but I've not managed to isolate a simple or stand-alone case which elicits it. In particular, I haven't yet seen it when running the script from the Perl debugger (I can get it when debugging a script which uses IPC::Open3 to run my target script.)

I realise that this is just possibly a bug in Perl, but much more likely to be something I'm doing, very likely round my calls to SVN::Client; but I'm stumped for a way to investigate it, and I wondered if anybody had any pointers.

Perl 5.10.0; Various versions of Fedora Linux. I'm going to try it on Perl 5.12, but unless it manifests there too, it won't really help me. 
**Edit**: a particular case which reliably gives the message in 5.10 doesn't in 5.12. Unfortunately that doesn't really tell me anything.

Comment: 5.14 is the current release of Perl.  5.12 and 5.10 are rather old.  But anyway, compile perl with debugging so that you can see what created the SV at 0xa6e685c.  This should point you in the right direction.  (My guess is that SVN::Client or another XS module is broken.)

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but I wrote a long article about this particular topic that should help with debugging: [The Dreaded "Attempt to free unreferenced scalar"](http://blog.booking.com/the-dreaded-attempt-to-free-unreferenced-scalar.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is often associated with threading issues, specifically in passing a variable from one thread to a subroutine running in another. Here's an abstract example of the pattern:

**A.pl**

```
....
my $dummy;
threads->create("B::c", ($dummy));
....
```

**B.pm**

```
....
sub c{...}
....
```

I realize that searching for something that resembles this in your "load of locally-written modules" won't be easy. Perhaps you can cut out chunks of your program until you find something that makes a difference in behavior; that should help you isolate the problem.

Comment: You should give a link to the original post (I also found it on google).

Comment: This is not just a repost, but yes, the sample code and basic idea was taken from http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1346880&page=133 . I confirmed the idea at several other links before composing this reply. I should have given credit to start with.

Comment: I'm 99.9% certain we don't use threads in our code. Maybe a standard or CPAN module does. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I also run into these messages a lot (in code that uses `fork` a lot) and the related problem of segmentation faults during the global destruction phase (that is, the program can complete normally, but an error during global destruction can make the program exit with a non-zero exit code). I also don't know whether these problems can be fixed, but they usually can be worked around.

First, use a global variable to detect whether you are in the global destruction phase:

```
our $_GLOBAL_DESTRUCTION = 0;
END { $_GLOBAL_DESTRUCTION = 1; }
```

(see also the [`${^GLOBAL_PHASE}`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24%7B%5EGLOBAL_PHASE%7D) variable available in Perl v>=5.13.7)

Then avoid running the troublesome code during the global destruction phase:

```
sub MyObject::DESTROY {
    return if $_GLOBAL_DESTRUCTION;
    ... # else proceed 
}

sub other_function_that_frees_unreferenced_scalars {
    return if $_GLOBAL_DESTRUCTION;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to skip global destruction, but if you're using XS modules that can't survive fork + destroy, they need to be fixed.  If pure perl code is doing this, please file a perl bug report!

Comment: The specific situation I have in mind is a SIGCHLD handler that updates a lot of state when a child process is reaped. Now suppose the main program ends, and in the middle of global destruction, an earlier child process ends and the SIGCHLD handler gets called. There's no point updating anything because the main program is over, and half of the stuff you would be updating has been garbage collected (but only half). So you tell your signal handler that it doesn't need to do anything once the END queue has started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't know what "the troublesome code" is. I think it very likely it's in the Subversion bindings, which I have no control over. The question is whether it's just a bug in them, or whether it is a result of a dodgy call I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any typeglobs that reference pointers e.g. a typeglob for a hash of hashes.  I ran into this with a typeglob used to switch between different hashes of arrays.  The error arose when entries were deleted using both the typeglob and the original hash name.  Either using a simple hash without nesting or getting rid of the typeglob eliminated the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach (@var)` is another good candidate for inspection.

The following code gave me this warning:

```
foreach (@list1) {
    my ($i, $j) = @$_;
    my $k = get_k($i, $j);
    foreach (@$k) {
        sub_that_uses_fork($_);
    }
}
```

But the following did not:

```
while (scalar(@list1)) {
    my ($i, $j) = @{shift(@list1)};
    my $k = get_k($i, $j);
    foreach (@$k) {
        sub_that_uses_fork($_);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this error. What I was doing was returning a mortalised SV using the `RETVAL` mechanism, when what I needed in that situation was to use `newSV(0)`.