# What is this error “Attempt to free unreferenced scalar”?

Tags: node.js, perl, segmentation-fault

I am invoking a perl script from nodejs and getting errors like:

```
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x15810d8 during global destruction.
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x15810d8 during global destruction.
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x15cffb8 during global destruction.
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x15cffb8 during global destruction.
Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone tell me which kind of error is this and how to debug it because it is simply ending the node process without giving any valuable information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848420/how-to-investigate-attempt-to-free-unreferenced-scalar

Comment: It means you've found a bug in an XS module or a Perl itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect, it is Perl/XS's equivalent of a double-`free()` bug. It indicates that some SV has been unreferenced twice from XS code (likely once during some cleanup, and then once again during the `FREETMPS` between statements). This is indicative of some kind of bug in some XS code you have called; possibly indirectly several layers down.

Comment: is there any method to find out which variable at address 0x15810d8 is causing this error?? as it is very hard to diagnose every variable in your code , specially when you are working on big project? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unfortunately the SV has already been deleted by the time that address is printed; that's the whole problem. However, it's usually possible to make some "likely guesses", print addresses of those in the function as it's running, and see if any match up with the printed address.

Comment: Another technique is to use a whole-image memory snapshot tool (e.g. Devel::MAT::Dumper) to grab the entire interpreter state at some moment likely in time, and then search it afterwards for an SV at that address